# distribute floating divs with same number of columns for each row depending on device width

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am developing a web page where I have floating divs with fixed width.
I would need to redistribute them, using jquery, in load event, by rows, having nearly the same columns in each row. I must do it depending on device width.

If divs total number is odd I understand it's not possible to have same column number in last row.

Anyone knows how to accomplish it?

Thanks in advance.

Fran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html), a JavaScript grid layout library which will do what you want.

Import the library, and you're ready to go :

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>

<script>
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 160
});
</script>
```

Example on CodePen : [Masonry example](https://codepen.io/Mnevis/pen/XWXVYpM)

Comment: Hello Mnevla:Thank you for your post.I need something different. In case there are two rows , first with 4 elements and second with only two, I need to redistribute elements with same number in each row. For the example I comment woul be 3 in one line and other 3 in second line.